Testing changing state value also changing mocked value
I have the following test:
it('increaseUpvote Should increase Upvote of selected book', () =\> {
    const store = useBooksStore()
    store.$patch({ books: mockBooks })
    expect(store.books[0].upvotes).toBe(1111)
    store.increaseUpvote(mockBooks[0].slug)
    expect(store.books[0].upvotes).toBe(1112)
})

I realized that increaseUpvote is doing what is told. but it's also changing the value on mockBooks not just on state.books as I expected it to be.
Does anyone know why?
I was expecting this other version of the test to work was well:
it('increaseUpvote Should increase Upvote of selected book', () => {
    const store = useBooksStore()
    store.$patch({ books: mockBooks })
    expect(store.books[0].upvotes).toBe(mockBooks[0].upvotes)
    store.increaseUpvote(mockBooks[0].slug)
    expect(store.books[0].upvotes).toBe(mockBooks[0].upvotes +1)
}) 

I also tried to use a copy of mockBooks with a spread operator [...mockBooks], but still the upvotes change on mockBooks as well.

Objects and arrays in JavaScript are assigned by reference, not by value. So by creating a deep copy of mockbooks, you can achieve this.  Here you can check.

The problem is the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79027320 , "Please, provide stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There should be no place for guesswork. But currently it looks like you pass "book" objects by reference, and it's totally expected that they are changed if you change them in another place they were passed (i.e. inside a store). [...mockBooks] shallowly copies an array but not objects it contain. If this is undesirable behaviour, deep clone them. You can use structuredClone but only if mockBooks is plain object and not Vue proxy (this isn't shown)"
